# Devise Invitable - Update user associated tables only in callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, devise-invitable

I'm trying to do a test send using

u = User.invite!({:email => "myemail@live.com", :name => "John Doe"}, User.find(1))

<s>Why is Devise Invitable trying to insert into tables companies and company_roles with wierd/wrong values when I'm actually expecting only the user table to be updated.</s>

<s>This behaviour causes a ROLLBACK since the invite does not have the correct values to update these tables.</s>

I only want to save stuff like company_role in the callback after the user has accepted an invite. How do I do this in the callback function and how do I access the initial values sent by the invite.

For example, can I do this?

```
       u = @referrer.invite!({
          email: params[:email],
          title: params[:title],
          first_name: params[:first_name],
          last_name: params[:last_name],
          website: @website,
          company_id: @company,
          country: @country,

        }, @referrer)
```

And then later retrieve some of the values in the accept callback using this in the User model?

```
after_invitation_accepted :email_invited_by
def email_invited_by
   # ...
end
```

Comment: does your company model consist `devise :invitable`

Comment: no, it is only on the User model.

Comment: using gem 'devise', '>=3.2.2',
gem 'devise_invitable', '=1.3.3

Comment: ok can you please post your models

Comment: Found the problem in the after_create and before_save for User...

Comment: not sure how to exclude those behaviours from create-user-by-invite, I only want those behaviours to happen maybe after the invited user has accepted.